# MongoDB Compass is Missing Schema Tab

Tags: mongodb, tabs, schema, compass

I just downloaded Mongodb and my compass gui doesn't have the Schema tab. Do any of you know how to get it back? I haven't been able to find a way.

Comment: what versions have you installed?

Comment: There are [several editions of Compass](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/#compass-compass-community-and-readonly-editions). The MongoDB 3.6 installer includes Compass Community. The Schema Analysis feature is part of the full version of Compass which is part of a commercial support subscription for production use cases (but free to use for evaluation and development). All Compass editions are available from the [MongoDB download centre](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#compass).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Actually I got the same problem, but the wrong thing that I was done is opening the MongoDB compass community.

Later when I opened MongoDB compass I found schema.
You should know that there are 2 compass. Make sure you opened MongoDB compass but not MongoDB compass community.

Comment: the community edition is now apparently deprecated, 
they posted instructions on how to migrate https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/upgrade/#migrate-from-community

Answer (score 0):

Stennie was right. I was using the Community version of Compass. The Schema tab appeared when I installed the normal version of Compass.

Answer (score 0):

The Schema tab is visible but the Apply option is missing? Compass Version (1.16.3 Stable)) did not offer the Enterprise or Community Option on the download page.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question

The answer is exactly right don't use community edition use stable edition to schema tab on the compass

https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/compass?tck=docs_compass